# Method chaining in C

Tags: c, method-chaining

Is it possible in C to do method chaining in the following way:

```
// is this the closest to item.find('path').find('subpath') ?
item -> find('path') -> find('subpath')
```

Or is this construction not really possible? If it's possible (or a variation of it), what might be the most basic example?

```
// like an XML hierarchical path
typedef struct Item {
    char *path;
    find (??)
} Path;
```

Comment: C doesn't have methods. Are you sure you don't mean C++?

Comment: @Barmar yea, I've never written C++ -- I mean the C functions.

Comment: You can put function pointers in structures. `struct Item* (*find)(char *);`

Comment: But unlike methods, the function doesn't automatically receive the object that pointed to it as an argument. So there's no way for it to know which `Item` you're searching.

Comment: Literally the struct of function pointers won't really allows multiple member function pointers to be chained as `a->func1()->func2()` without a further cludge of the function returning a pointer to that type struct which would then be further chained.. You can use one member access with `->`, but multiple wold fail because, e.g.  `a->func1()` doesn't have a member named `func2()`. C has no built-in syntax for function chaining with `->`.